# Jquery compare 2 type of array by id and remove an object where the id is not equal

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 type of array, and I need to remove the object where id is not present in the first array,
this is my arrays

```
var cityArr = [
    "1:City 1",
    "2:City 2",
    "3:City 3",

];
var cityEvent = [
        {
            "2": {
                "day": "13",
                "hour": "10:00"
            },
            "3": {
                "day": "15",
                "hour": "20:30"
            },
            "1": {
                "day": "12",
                "hoyr": "17:50"
            },
            "4": {
                "day": "18",
                "hour": "19:00"
            },
        }
    ];


// return new array without id 4
var cityEventUpdate = [
        {
            "2": {
                "day": "13",
                "hour": "10:00"
            },
            "3": {
                "day": "15",
                "hour": "20:30"
            },
            "1": {
                "day": "12",
                "hoyr": "17:50"
            }
        }
    ];
```

Can anyone please help me, I have tested various solutions finded here but not work with my arrays

Comment: Please show what you think is your best attempt to solve it. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: I suggest you first extract the IDs from `cityArr` into a separate array. Then you can just use `filter()` and `includes()` to test if the array is found.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :-)

```
var props = ['id'];

var result = cityArr.filter(function(o1){
    // filter out (!) items in result2
    return !cityEvent.some(function(o2){
        return o1.id === o2.id;          // assumes unique id
    });
}).map(function(o){
    // use reduce to make objects with only the required properties
    // and map to apply this to the filtered array as a whole
    return props.reduce(function(cityEventUpdate, id){
        cityEventUpdate[id] = o[id];
        return cityEventUpdate;
    }, {});
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(cityEventUpdate))
```

my mistake was putting [0] in the second array